# Laravel Trying to delete MySQL row that was added last

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to delete the last row that was added in a MySQL table with a specific userID. I am currently getting the following error when I click on my button.

Fatal error: Call to a member function Where() on integer

Here is my code in the blade file where the button is

```
<div class="element1">
  {{ HTML::image('progress2/Icons/Meetings_Icon.png', 'alt', array('width' =>150)) }}
   <div class="text1">
 <form action="{{ route("progress") }}" method="post">
    <button class="styleHover styleButton"> + </button> </form>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; 5 &nbsp; &nbsp;
<form action="{{route("progressDeincrement") }}" method="post">
 <button class="styleHover styleButton"> - </button>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Here is the code in my route file

```
Route:: post("progressDeincrement", [
  "as" => "progressDeincrement",
  "uses" => "tableController@delete"
]);
```

Here is the code in my controller

```
public function delete() 
{
   $idForDelete = DB :: table("users_has_activities") -> max("pointsID") -> 
  Where("usersID", "=", "12");
  DB:: table("users_has_activities") -> Where("pointsID", "=",  $idForDelete) ->  
delete();
}
```

The + button is able to add a row to the MySQL table, however, deleting a row is proving to be a challenge for me.

Comment: try change position on calling .. eg ... table->where->max() because max is probably similar as delete etc .. and run the query so must be at least

Comment: wow thanks for all the responses @kirkbeard ur suggestion worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce this to a single DB query:

```
DB::table("users_has_activities")
    ->where("usersID", "=", "12")
    ->orderBy("pointsID", "DESC")
    ->take(1)
    ->delete();
```

This will give you an SQL query like:

```
DELETE FROM users_has_activities
WHERE usersID = '12'
ORDER BY `pointsID` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Using a combination of `Order By column DESC` and `LIMIT 1` ensures you will get the highest ID available, therefore mimicking the behaviour of `MAX()`.

Comment: Use the limit is good thing if you want get last row but he want to delete the last record by id so the max would be great because he need get only id and not a whole row data.

Comment: ofc you are right, but the question was "Iam getting error in my script" and not "How to optimalize my query or source". This answer told "use this copy&paste and will work" but not give understand to asker where had problem. So I feel the next question might be "Iam getting error in query" IMHO. =)

Answer (score 0):

I guess `max("pointsID")` returns an integer and you're trying to use `Where` clause on integer and not on a model or a collection.

Maybe you want to use this:

```
$idForDelete = DB::table('users_has_activities')->where('usersID', '12')->max('pointsID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and use `first()` with `ordering descending`:

```
$idForDelete = DB :: table("users_has_activities") ->where("usersID", "=", 12)->orderBy('pointsID', 'DESC')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says the `max()` function must be called at latest place, because it run the query.

Look at example in Aggregates.

Use Case is ... Table -> filter results -> fetch what i want eg Fetch one, Fetch all, delete, update etc..

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates